# Intel XDK information

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I am new in hybrid app. I seen there are many open source framework available to develop an app. Yesterday i chosen Phonegap for that and downloaded the desktop app. Today when i was searching i knew that i can  develop 25 public app and just 1 private app using that. Also it has an limit of app size. So i am confused which platform should i use. I want to know that in Intel XDK, is there any limit of app size or public and private app issues ?? Or it has an enterprise edition available?? I didn't found the answers of this question So i am posting here to get answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hybrid application is one of the future core development section. I prefer to use Intel xdk to build the hybrid application. Intel xdk is free to  [download](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) in any platform. If you are new to Hybrid application, then use the Intel XDK for developing your application. Download the SDK and create a new project and you can edit the index.html page in the www folder. After completing the coding, you can build your android/ios/windows/chrome/web application by selecting the build tab and provide certificates and build with just click start building.

Please follow the link to get some beginners tutorial 
1.[qnimate](http://qnimate.com/post-series/intel-xdk-complete-training/)
2.[sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/coding-first-cross-platform-app-intel-xdk/)

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my question is It's totally free? Like in phonegap i can create 25 apps in free then after i need to pay. So intel xdk is totally free?

Comment: Its totally free like phone-gap. You can build as much as you can . You need to create a free certificate to build android application. for ios you need a developer account(apple) , by using the adhoc and provision certificates from apple account to build ios app. Still have any question ,feel free to ask. please up the answer by click the upper arrow